# Return multiple columns based on date range using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm basically trying to calculate revenue to date using pandas. I would like to return N columns consisting of each quarter end. Each column would calculate total revenue to date as of that quarter end. I have:

```
df['Amortization_per_Day'] = (2.5, 3.2, 5.5, 6.5, 9.2)
df['Start_Date'] = ('1/1/2018', '2/27/2018', '3/31/2018', '5/23/2018', '6/30/2018') 
Date_Range = pd.date_range('10/31/2017', periods=75, freq='Q-Jan')
```

and want to do something like:

```
df['Amortization_per_Day'] * (('Date_Range' - df['Start_Date']).dt.days + 1)
```

for each date within the Date_Range. I'm not sure how to pass the Date_Range through the function and to return N columns. I've been reading about zip(*df) and shift but not fully grasping it. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Here's a complete solution:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Amortization_per_Day'] = (2.5, 3.2, 5.5, 6.5, 9.2)
df['Start_Date'] = ('1/1/18', '2/27/18', '3/31/18', '5/23/2018', '6/30/2018') 
df['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Date'])
dr = pd.date_range('10/31/2017', periods=75, freq='Q-Jan')

def betweendates(x, y):
    xv = x.values.astype('datetime64[D]')
    xpad = np.zeros(xv.size + 2, dtype=xv.dtype)
    xpad[1:-1] = xv
    xpad[0],xpad[-1] = np.datetime64(datetime.min), np.datetime64(datetime.max)

    yv = y.values.astype('datetime64[D]')

    return (xpad[:-1] <= yv[:,None]) & (xpad[1:] >= yv[:,None])

# get a boolean array that indicates which dates in dr are in between which dates in df['Start_Date']
btwn = betweendates(df['Start_Date'], dr)

# based on the boolean array btwn, select out the salient rows from df and dates from dr
dfsel = df[btwn[:, 1:].T]
drsel = dr[btwn[:, 1:].sum(axis=1, dtype=bool)]

# do the actual calculation the OP wanted
dfsel['Amortization_per_Day'] * ((drsel - dfsel['Start_Date']).dt.days + 1)
```

Output:

```
0       77.5
2      170.5
4      294.4
4     1140.8
4     1987.2
4     2806.0
4     3652.4
4     4498.8
4     5345.2
4     6173.2
      ...   
4    52394.0
4    53212.8
4    54059.2
4    54905.6
4    55752.0
4    56570.8
4    57417.2
4    58263.6
4    59110.0
4    59938.0
Length: 74, dtype: float64
```

## Explanation

The boolean `btwn` array looks like this:

```
[[ True False False False False False]
 [False  True False False False False]
 [False False False  True False False]
 [False False False False False  True]
 [False False False False False  True]
 [False False False False False  True]
 [False False False False False  True]
 [False False False False False  True]
 [False False False False False  True]
 [False False False False False  True]
 [False False False False False  True]
 [False False False False False  True]
 [False False False False False  True]
 ...
```

The `i`th row of `btwn` corresponds to the `i`th datetime in your date range. In each row, exactly one value will be `True`, and the others will be `False`. A `True` value in the `0`th column indicates that the datetime is before any of the `Start_Times`, a `True` value in the `1`st column indicates that the datetime is in between the `0`th and the `1`st dates in `Start_Times`, and so forth. A `True` value in the last column indicates that the datetime is after any of the `Start_Times`.

By slicing `btwn` like this:

```
btwn[:, 1:]
```

it can be used to match up datetimes in your date range with the immediately preceding `Start_Time`. If you instead change the slices of `btwn` to be like this:

```
btwn[:, :-1]
```

you would end up matching each datetime to the next `Start_Time` instead.

Comment: Wow, thank you! This was incredibly helpful and a lot more detailed than what I was expecting.

Comment: Well, I may have gone a little overboard. I'm still learning Pandas too :) Also, if the answer solves your problem, you should [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)